# How to insert data from a CSV file into Hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata

I already have a table created and need to insert data from a csv file.

Comment: can you provide examples on what you've already tried?

Comment: I've already created this table as an example: 

create table table_test(name string, last_name string) 
row format delimited
fields terminated by ','
lines terminated by '\n'
stored as textfile location '/datastore/files/test/';

But what I need is INSERT INTO table_test (name, last_name) VALUES....
So in the values ​​I need to insert the data from a CSV file without having to create a new table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, let's say you have a table with 3 columns say employee table.

Step1:

```
hive> CREATE TABLE employee (id int, name string, salary double) row format delimited fields terminated by ',';
```

Step2:

```
hive> LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '/home/employee.csv' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE employee;
```

Step3:

```
hive> select * from employee;
```

Comment: Thanks it worked but I want insert and not overwrite...How can I do it?

Comment: Just omit `OVERWRITE`

Answer (score 1):

If you create an external table with a location and upload the CSV to that location directory, then you can query it.

Otherwise, you can use `LOAD DATA` commands

Answer (score 1):

You can create table using command given below with location of your csv file:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE base_table (
 ID int, 
 Name string,
 Contact_No bigint,
 Time_stamp string
 )
 ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
 LOCATION '/user/hive/base_table';
```